# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length in R Shiny reactive plot

Tags: r, plot, shiny, interactive

I am building an app in Shiny (R) that does a number of things:
-Ask for a plausible range of values
-Use this range to determine the plot dimensions (x-axis limits and intervals)
-Create an interactive plot (with these derived dimensions) that reacts to clicks
-Record the click location (in particular the interval in which the participant has clicked and the height (ceiling(y-coordinate)) of the most recent click.

I am having trouble with the last step. I am trying to record the location of the click in a matrix but the error message 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length' pops up.

I have tried displaying the length of each argument on screen (in the Shiny app) and the length of both seems to be 1.

Where am I going wrong?

I have tried to simplify the code as much as possible, simplifying it any further by replacing functions with numbers allows for simpler code and so removes the problem.  The first section of the code is to make it reproducible, all functions are definitely correct so they don't need to be checked. It is renderTable in Server code that is causing problems.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
gridheight<-10 # the plot is always 10 cells high

matrix1<-matrix(data=0, nrow=4,ncol=31) # matrix for collecting data about click locations

binwlist<-c(1,2,5,10,20,50,100) #possible intervals sizes (or bin widths)
lowertable<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=1000, ncol=length(binwlist)+1,
                   dimnames=list(c(1:1000),c("min",binwlist))) #lower limit for x axis for each input minimum
uppertable<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=1000, ncol=length(binwlist)+1,
               dimnames=list(c(1:1000),c("max",binwlist))) #upper limit for x axis for each input maximum
lowertable[,1]<-1:1000
uppertable[,1]<-1:1000

for (i in 2:ncol(lowertable)) {
  lowertable[,i]<-ifelse(((floor(lowertable[,1]/binwlist[i-1])*binwlist[i-1]-binwlist[i-1]))
                         <=0,0,
                         (floor(lowertable[,1]/binwlist[i-1])*binwlist[i-1] -binwlist[i-1]))
}

for (i in 2:ncol(uppertable)) {
  uppertable[,i]<-ifelse(((ceiling(uppertable[,1]/binwlist[i-1])*binwlist[i-1]+binwlist[i-1]))
                         >=1000,1000,
                         (ceiling(uppertable[,1]/binwlist[i-1])*binwlist[i-1]+binwlist[i-1]))
}

##### functions for determining plot dimensions ####

fbinwmat<-function(a,b)
  ((uppertable[b,2:ncol(uppertable)]-lowertable[a,2:ncol(lowertable)])/binwlist)

fbinwcol<-function(a,b) #pick the column that will give as close to 12 bins(intervals) as possible
(which.min(apply(matrix((abs(fbinwmat(a,b)-12)),nrow=1),MARGIN=2,min))) 

fbinwidth<-function(a,b) #binwidth so there is as close to 12 bins as possible
  (binwlist[fbinwcol(a,b)])

flower<-function(a,b) #lower limit (x-axis) at that bin width
  lowertable[a,fbinwcol(a,b)]

fupper<-function(a,b) #upper limit (x-axis) at that bin width
  uppertable[b,fbinwcol(a,b)] 

fnbins<-function(a,b)
  ((fupper(a,b)-flower(a,b))/fbinwidth(a,b))

fbin.left<-function(a,b)
  (seq(from=flower(a,b),to=(fupper(a,b)-fbinwidth(a,b)),length=fnbins(a,b)))

fbin.right<-function(a,b)
  (seq(from=(flower(a,b)+fbinwidth(a,b)),to=fupper(a,b),length=fnbins(a,b)))
```

UI

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive plot with reactive coordinates"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("minimum", label="x-axis minimum", value=13, min=0, max=31),
      numericInput("maximum", label="x-axis maximum", value=23, min=0, max=31)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1", click="location"),
      textOutput("text"),
      TableOutput("table")
    )
  )
))
```

Servier code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  bin.width<-reactive({fbinwidth(input$minimum,input$maximum)})    
  nbins<-reactive({fnbins(input$minimum,input$maximum)})
  lower<-reactive({flower(input$minimum,input$maximum)})
  upper<-reactive({fupper(input$minimum,input$maximum)})
  bin.left<-reactive({fbin.left(input$minimum,input$maximum)})
  bin.right<-reactive({fbin.right(input$minimum,input$maximum)})

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(ps=15)
    plot(c(lower(),upper()),c(0,0),
         xlim=c(lower(),upper()),
         ylim=c(-1,gridheight),type="l",
         ylab="",
         xaxp=c(lower(),upper(),nbins()),
         xlab="Number of rainy days")


    for(i in 1:nbins()){
      lines(c(bin.left()[i],bin.left()[i]),
            c(0,gridheight),lty=3,col=8)
    }

    lines(c(bin.right()[nbins()],bin.right()[nbins()]),
          c(0,gridheight),lty=3,col=8)

    for(i in 1:gridheight){
      lines(c(lower(),upper()),c(i,i), lty=3,col=8)
    }
  })

  output$table<-renderTable({
    for (i in bin.right()){
      matrix1[1,i]<- reactive({
        ifelse (input$location$x>(i-bin.width()),
                (ifelse(input$location$x<=i,
                        input$location$x, 0)),0)
        })
      matrix1[2,i]<- reactive({
        ifelse (input$location$x>(i-bin.width()),(ifelse(input$location$x<=i,
                        input$location$y, 0)),0)
        })
      matrix1[3,i]<- reactive({
        ifelse (input$location$x>(i-bin.width()),
                (ifelse(input$location$x<=i,
                        (ceiling(input$location$x/bin.width())-input$minimum/bin.width()), 0)),0)
      })
      matrix1[4,i]<- reactive({
        ifelse (input$location$x>(i-bin.width()),
                (ifelse(input$location$x<=i,
                        (ceiling(max(input$location$y,0))), 0)),0)
      })
    }
    })

  output$text<-renderText({

    paste("x:", input$location$x,br(),
          "y:", input$location$y,br(),
          "bin number:", ceiling(input$location$x/bin.width())*bin.width(),
          br(),
          "bin height:", ceiling(max(input$location$y,0)))
  })


})
```